# JavaScript - multiline template literals when source code has tabs in front

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a JS multiline [*template literal*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like this:

```
function _on_message_arrived(_m) {

    // Feedback.
    console.log(
        `FUNCTION: "_on_message_arrived()":
             String (glyphs): ${_m.payloadString}
             String (hex):    ${_m.payloadBytes}`
    );
}
```

But because there are **tabs** in 2nd and 3rd lines, these tabs are also printed in the browser's console *(I colored them in red)*:

[image]

How can I format the JS source code so that it resembles what I get in multiple lines? That is when I am using **tabs** in the source code to indent the code and I am also using *template literal*.

Comment: You can replace the tabs, something like `\`...\`.replace(/\t/g, '\s\s\s\s')`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to resort to wrecking your code's indentation, unfortunately:

```js
function _on_message_arrived(_m) {
  // Feedback.
  console.log(
`FUNCTION: "_on_message_arrived()":
     String (glyphs): ${_m.payloadString}
     String (hex):    ${_m.payloadBytes}`
  );
}
```

Comment: Noooooooooo! ;((( I don't want this kind of solution. :)

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of whitespaces and try to make poor man's content management system.

```js
const data = {
  payloadString: '26.9',
  payloadBytes: '50,54,46,57'
}

function _on_message_arrived(_m) {

  const padStuff = (match, offset, string) => {
    return Array(Number(match.replace('<', '').replace('>', ''))).fill('\t').join('');
  }
  
  // Feedback.
  console.log(
    `FUNCTION: "_on_message_arrived()":
        <1>String (glyphs): ${_m.payloadString}
        <2>String (hex):    ${_m.payloadBytes}`.replace(/ +?/g, '').replace(/\<(?<year>\d+)\>/g, padStuff));
}

_on_message_arrived(data);
```